# Simple way of handling a load of incoming data (from a user using a console)

Tags: java

What would be a good way of handling a load of data (json strings) being written to the console by a user (reading one line at a time).
The jsons need to be processed and then set to some hash map/embedded DB.

It is a small and simple spring project so need to keep things simple as possible.

Once the program is exited (by the user) there is no need to keep the data.

**EDIT:**

I am more concern with the program ability to handle the input quick enough not to cause a significant latency then the actual json lib to use.
In that sense would it be more efficient to use an embedded DB or a simple POJO wrapping a hashmap (assuming the amount of data can be held in-memory)

Comment: Save every line in a string buffer then execute the json (maybe with gson?) using stringBuffer.toString().. If your json is small (or big too maybe?) it could be an idea..

Comment: There are many JSON parsing libraries out there, [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) would be my personal favorite, but your use case may vary.

Comment: Problem that you are dealing with is that user is putting data line by line and you dont know where it ends. Consider switching it, to reading data from file. Path to this file could be provided by user in a single line.

Answer (score 1):

As i have said in the comments, you could do something like this:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        try
        {
            while (!(line = bufferedReader.readLine()).equals("#"))
            {
                json.append(line);
            }

            System.out.println(json);
            Test test = new Gson().fromJson(json.toString(), Test.class);
            System.out.println(test);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class Test
{
    private int hello;
    private int world;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Test{" +
                "hello=" + hello +
                ", world=" + world +
                '}';
    }
}
```

It reads user input until he writes "#", i have used Gson (best JSON library for me) and a sample Test class just to do a test and it's ok. Maybe with some big json you can have some problems but it could be crazy to let user write big json codes in the console. Use a file if you need something of long.

Comment: Better would be to use the EOD character (ctrl-d in most terminals) - that is a more standard way to say to a still-running program that the stream is done.

Comment: Thanks marco and dimo.
I actually use GSON. As you mentioned it is a great lib.
I also have "\n" as a line separator and EOF as an end of input.
I am more concern with the program ability to handle the input quick enough not to cause a significant latency.

Comment: # was just an example, you can use everything you want. Anyway, your problem is solved now?

Comment: @Queequeg - if you want to submit a new question on this topic, please be more clear what it is that you don't know what to do, and what you're concerned could be the problem.  You already seem to have a JSON parser, and you are already reading in input and working with it, so what are you having trouble with?  Including an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) often helps tremendously.